# U.S. Census data for particular addresses?

Tags: geospatial, usa, us-census, census, spatial

Is there a way to get [United States Census mapping data](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files.html) for a particular addressees, or are [TIGER](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/tiger/info)'s blocks and tracts the finest spatial resolution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [technical documentation](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgrshp2023/TGRSHP2023_TechDoc.pdf), section 4-12-5, they don't have individual addresses, but address ranges:

> **Address Ranges**
>
> The address range feature county-based shapefile contains the geospatial edge geometry and attributes of all
> unsuppressed address ranges for a county or county equivalent area.
> All the TIGER/Line address range files contain potential address
> ranges, not individual addresses.
>
> Potential ranges include the full range of possible structure numbers
> even though the actual structures may not exist. The Census Bureau
> suppresses single-address address ranges in order to maintain the
> confidentiality of the described addresses as specified by Title 13 of
> the U.S. Code, and does not currently provide any address ranges for
> the Island Areas.

You can find the files for 2023 at the following address: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2023/ . The pdf file at the root of the directory gives an explanation of the files included in the subdirectories. You may be interested in particular by the "ADDR", "ADDRFEAT", and "ADDRFN" subdirectories.

The data seems divided in multiple files for various zones (I didn't find a file containing all the data at once, but I may have missed it), so it might require scripting from your part, depending on your use case.

On how to use these files, Section 5-1 and appendix L-5 of the technical documentation will give you technical details. If you need specific advice on how to use the files for your use case, this is a different question that would probably require you to tell how you intend to use these files. In this case, maybe ask a question on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ if you encounter technical difficulties when using these data.

Related: [How do I from convert from street level address to block/block group/census track?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75870/how-do-i-from-convert-from-street-level-address-to-block-block-group-census-trac)